# ... (three dots) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at the documentation page for jScroll plugin for jQuery (http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo) and I noticed this :

```
$(...).scrollTo( $('ul').get(2).childNodes[20], 800 );
```

So, what does the three dots in jQuery mean ? I have never seen this selector before

EDIT :

DOM Element

This is from the source HTML. Viewing the source for the following links :

```
Relative 
selectorjQuery 
objectDOM 
ElementAbsolute 
numberAbsolute
```

all give the same implementation.

EDIT : I didnt look at the attribute clearly, its for the title attribute. I assumed its the href attribute. Feel silly asking this question now :) Thanks for the answers

Comment: It basically is a placeholder for your selection.

Comment: It's hardly a valid selector. My best guess is they wanted to say "any selector" ;)

Comment: ... - just for example.Three dots doesn't exits.

Comment: +1: It's a fair question, and one that I don't think has been asked before.

Comment: Upvoted because it doesnt deserve a down vote - genuine question which other people may ask

Comment: @jperovic: More to the point, since it's not in quotes, it's not a selector at all, it's invalid JavaScript syntax. So clearly a placeholder.

Comment: Why not link the documentation page you were looking at? Why link to something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am fairly certain that he was using that as an example.

`$( ... )` would be akin to `$( your-selector-here )`.

In other words, I have never seen any implementation of that.

Comment: In other words, it an ellipsis. Which basically means, truncated text was here.

Comment: Definitely just an example as quoted, since it's not in quotes (`...`, not `"..."`), and so would be invalid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Looking at the source code, the author has used it in each of the links I have updated my original post

Comment: Okay I see that it is specified as a title attribute, thats what added to my confusion. everything is clear now :) thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Typically ... is used in various docs to shorten the example, and it means that you put something in place of the dots, or that what you would put there was omitted (to shorten the example)

It's not actually valid JS syntax.

Answer (score 4):

It has no meaning. They meant just write your own selector.
Check out the [souce code](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/init.js)

```
$('div.pane').scrollTo( 0 );
```

Answer (score 4):

They are not syntactically correct. They are just way the author uses to say scroll to some element, the name of which I don't bother to write here so I just write dots. Check the source code of the page if in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Three dots in javascript is Spread Syntax see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

> allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals)